# JSON отправляю(используя Volley), а сервер пишет что Json пуст

Tags: java, android, json, post

Подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть не так с отправкой JSON'а в этом методе (использую Volley)?

```
public void jsonPost() {
    /*Post data*/
        Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

        jsonParams.put("user_id", "216");
        jsonParams.put("customer_id", "6664");
        jsonParams.put("operation", "minus");
        jsonParams.put("amount", "100");
        jsonParams.put("subject", "Тест");
        jsonParams.put("access_token", "VHvjY3TFsSrDlbCg2MaeHInvyRGqQchMUN5SQZyjRZWdbytelEs3mPyUHelyrCklpqegpMAhMwuX5YbrCEvYu3TbheKIR43huiyU58bRFGPLE1dgGIfaL9m2o6LgbPxF");
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonParams);
        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,

                jsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        txtResult.setText(response.toString());
                        txtResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        requestQueue.add(postRequest);
    }
```

Не могу разобраться почему сервер возвращает ошибку о том что json пуст.

Comment: Приведите и ответ сервера.

Comment: {"status":"error","code":"1","message":"json is empty"}

Comment: Обратитесь к документации по API или к разработчикам сервера, очень похоже что сервер просто ждет чего-то другого, чем вы ему посылаете.

Comment: я уже пытаюссь Postman'ом проверить, но ответ всё тот же(

Comment: А где у вас переменная "json"? Вы JSON просто в теле запроса отправляете, вот вас и не понимают.

Comment: а вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, подробнее объяснть как это организовать?

Comment: Я не пользуюсь Volley, все что могу сказать, что вам в теле запроса надо передать строку вида `json={ ... тут тело вашего JSON ... }`.